Proof of Wald's equation
I want to prove the following Propositon:

Let $X_1,X_2,...4$ be independent and identically distributed random
variables. Let $N$ be a integrer valued random variable that is
independent if the sequence $(X_n)$. Then
$E[X_1+...+X_N]=E[N]E[X_1]$.

I want to know if my calculations were correct.
Approach:
We can use the Law of total expectation to get $E(X_1+...+X_N)=E(E(X_1+...+X_N|N))$.
Since $E(X_1+...+X_N|N)$ is a random variable dependent on $N$, I like to write $h(N)$.
Since $E(X):=\sum_x x P(X=x)$ and $E(f(X))=\sum_x f(x) P(X=x)$.
So we can write $E(h(N))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h(k) P(N=k)$.
Note that $h(N)=E(X_1+...+X_N|N)$, thus $h(k)=E(X_1+...+X_N|N=k)$.
Togheter we get $E(h(N))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} E(X_1+...+X_N|N=k) P(N=k)$.
Further note that $E(X_1+...+X_N|N=k)=E(X_1|N=k)+...+E(X_N)|N=k=N E(X_1|N=k)$ and that since (X_n) and N are independent $E(X_1|N=k)=E(X_1)$.
Putting all those things togheter we get
$E(X_1+...+X_N)=E(E(X_1+...+X_N|N))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} E(X_1+...+X_N|N=k) P(N=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k E(X_1|N=k) P(N=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k P(N=k) E(X_1|N=k)=E(N)E(X_1)$.

It seems a little verbose, but   $E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)=E(X_1\mid N=k)+\cdots+E(X_N\mid N=k) = k E(X_1\mid N=k)$ would be correct as is your argument using the independnece of $N$ and $X_1$  for this being $k E(X_1)$.  So $E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k) = NE(X_1)$ and  $E[E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)]=E[NE(X_1)]=E[N]E(X_1)$.

Correct, but you can shortcut:
$$E[X_1+\dots+ X_N] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E[X_1+\dots + X_n,N=n]= \sum_{n=1}^\infty E[X_1+\dots+ X_n]P(N=n)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty E[X_1]n P(N=n) = E[X_1]E[N].$$
